# When Referring to a Set of Equations Referenced by a Label "(4)," Do I Say "Equation 4," "Equations 4," or "Equation Set 4"?

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

I'm writing a math paper in LaTeX, and sometimes use \begin{equation} \label{eqn:AnEquation} ... \end{equation} to set the equation apart from the text and to give it a label I'll later reference.  Further down in the document I might write something like "Refer to Equation~\ref{eqn:AnEquation}".
So far, so good; but suppose I use have multiple equations aligned one over the other.  Then the label refers to a *set* of equations rather than just one.  What is the preferred wording to reference the set?  "Refer to Equation..."?  "Refer to Equations..."?  "Refer to Equation Set..."?

Comment: 'Equations' is probably clearer, as otherwise one might interpret it as a reference to the single equation in the line with the number. 'set of equations' might be an overkill, except if the collection of equations forms a recurring entity. But I'm sure that acceptance and reception of your paper will not hinge on the way you put this reference.